# Mule compilation failed with maven : Invalid content was found starting with element 'db:generic-config'

Tags: java, maven, mule

I got blocked for two days for a damned dependency problem, so I decided to share the solution ;-).

I had the following error while running functional tests via Maven :

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'db:generic-config'.
One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, ..."}' is expected
```

The Mule xml was referencing a database config as follow:

```
<db:generic-config name="mf-connector-thebes"
    url="${url}"
    driverClassName="${driver}"
    doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" >
</db:generic-config>
```

Comment: It would be better if you would move the solution part of your question to an answer and accept it. That would flag this question as closed instead of the current "open but resolved" state...

Comment: I did what you suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem, simply add the following dependency to your pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have required namespace in your Mule config for `db:generic-config`

```
xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db
```

and schema location :-

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
```